# Reset default values of widgets without triggering their value-change listeners in Vaadin Flow 14 web app

Tags: java, vaadin, event-listener, vaadin-flow

I have several widgets for controlling the filtering of a list of items in a `Grid`. Each widget has a value-change listener, so when the user uses one of the widgets, filters on the data provider behind the `Grid` are configured, resulting in the `Grid` object displaying a subset of its items.

```
    strength = new RadioButtonGroup <>();  // Backed with enum named `Strength`. 
    strength.setLabel( "Strength:" );
    strength.setItems( Strength.values() );
    strength.setValue( Strength.ANY );
    strength.setRenderer( new TextRenderer <>( Strength :: getDisplayName ) );
    strength.addValueChangeListener( event -> {
        configureFilters();
    } );
```

This works well.

I also have *Reset* button to put those filter controls back to their default status.

```
    reset = new Button( "Reset" );
    reset.addClickListener( event -> {
        this.resetCriteria();
        this.configureFilters();
    } );
```

The `resetCriteria` method makes a series of these calls:

```
this.strength.setValue( Strength.ANY );
```

This causes problems. Resetting those widgets causes the value-change events to fire, and listeners the execute. This interrupt my series of `setValue( … )` calls. So some of the filter control widgets are not reset.

➥ Is there a way to suspend the value-change events from firing, or the listeners from listening, during the brief interlude when I reset all the widget values back to defaults?

Or is there an entirely different approach I should take to resetting widgets? I suppose I could discard the entire layout of widgets and recreate from scratch, but that seems like overkill, like there should be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in Vaadin version 8, there is a way to determine if the (value change) event has its origin from the user or is "synthetic" (generated by code).

See the method [`com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEvent#isFromClient`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentEvent.html#isFromClient--)

> **Class `ComponentEvent<T extends Component>`**
>
> `public boolean isFromClient()`
>
> Checks if this event originated from the client side.
>
> Returns:
>
> `true` if the event originated from the client side,  `false` otherwise

So you would check in your value change listener, if the given event
`isFromClient` and only do your logic then. Add `if ( event.isFromClient() )` to your code.

```
    strength.addValueChangeListener( event -> {
        if ( event.isFromClient() ) { this.configureFilters(); }
    } );
```

Otherwise there are (to my knowledge) no ways to silence the listeners
beside doing it yourself.  E.g.

- Remember the [`Registration`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/shared/Registration.html) from registering each listener, close them before, and re-add the listener again after you are done with changing the values.
- Build your own killswitch the listeners check, whether actions must be taken.